# How can I minimize the database load when inserting data into multiple tables and avoid data insertion failures using .NET 8 and Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am confused about how to improve **`performance`** and follow best practices for table insertion while minimizing **`database load`** and **`avoiding data insertion failures`**.

Using: 
**.Net Core 8** 
**Entity Farmwork Core 8** 
**MSSQL**

For a **User Profile**, I have a field called **`RetailerProfileId`**.

For a **Retailer Profile**, there are several fields:

- `OwnerId`
- `ManagerId`
- `HcblVolumeId`
- `PreferredBrandId`
- `LogisticCapabilityId`
- `OtherBusinessId`

Each of these **Entities** (e.g., `Owner`, `Manager`, `HcblVolume`, `PreferredBrand`, `LogisticCapability`, `OtherBusiness`) has 3/4 properties or more.

My current approach is to save these fields into the database one by one (`Owner`, `Manager`, `HcblVolume`, `PreferredBrand`, `LogisticCapability`, `OtherBusiness`).

After inserting each of these records, I obtain their respective primary keys and insert them as foreign keys into the Retailer Profile table.

Once this is complete, I then insert the Retailer Profile Id into the User Profile table.

Is this Approach good? Or should I consider using **`Batch Inserts`** or **`Transaction management`** for better performance and data integrity?

Comment: Why assigning IDs? Assigning navigation properties should do the job. EF Core will provide all needed IDs retrieving automatically.

Comment: Hello, @SvyatoslavDanyliv could you please give me demos?

Comment: `var rp = new RetailerProfile(); rp.Owner = new Owner(); context.Add(rp); context.SaveChanges()` - it should insert and connect two objects together.

Comment: @Syvatoslav, under the hood, wouldn't it be the same procedures?

Comment: In my opinion, you could write SP or Transaction  inside the sql and call it by using EF core instead of using EF to add the entity. This will be faster than using EF add.

Comment: If these are not all one-to-many, you could reduce the number of tables and that might be slightly more efficient.  (I mention that because you didn't say whether you were looking for existing entries before adding them.... usually the "one" with the many already exists... or has to be entered as a new one first... then it's just a matter of setting the foreign key.)